# How to assign multiple selection (checkbox) to gridview in c#

Tags: c#

We need multiple selection on gridview through checkboxes, how can we do it? Give me solution for this problem in C#.

Comment: Can you elaborate this more? Btw, is it ASP.NET? (then tag it accordingly). Please show what you've tried (SO is not a _"give me solution"-site_).

Comment: yes like this but we use c# .net, how it can done in c# .net

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
 <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14437/Extending-GridView-by-allowing-Multiple-Selections

Unique said: like this, but we use c# .net, how this can be used in c# .net

Update:

Try this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11207/Selecting-multiple-checkboxes-inside-a-GridView-co